# XAMPP netbeans xdebug doesn't work

Tags: php, windows, netbeans, xampp, xdebug

I've been using xampp on windows and netbeans for a while now and finally want to get the xdebug debugger working. For some reason it doesn't work.

My phpinfo() file doesn't show any xdebug information, even though I tried to tweak and change the php.ini file as Google suggested.

Here are the relevant parts of my php.ini file:

```
zend_extension = \xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.6-vc11.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote:autostart = on
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
; Port number must match debugger port number in NetBeans IDE Tools > Options > PHP
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

The remote_ports of the php.ini file and the netbeans debugger settings match.
I also made sure to edit the right php.ini file.

However: Even though my XAMPP works fine since I changed the ports to 8081 and 444, every time I start it, I get the following errors:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1ZsT.png

Also note that I use Windows 10 64bit rather than Windows 8 as it states.

My errorlog is a mess:

```
[Thu Sep 17 08:50:14.069550 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5768:tid 500] AH01909: www.example.com:444:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 17 08:50:14.159597 2015] [core:warn] [pid 5768:tid 500] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
Failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.6-vc11.dll
example.com:444:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 17 08:50:14.404611 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5768:tid 500] AH00455: Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.6.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 17 08:50:14.404611 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5768:tid 500] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 12 2015 10:56:48
[Thu Sep 17 08:50:14.404611 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5768:tid 500] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Sep 17 08:50:14.410612 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5768:tid 500] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7852
[Thu Sep 17 08:50:15.318272 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7852:tid 512] AH01909: www.example.com:444:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
Failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.6-vc11.dll
example.com:444:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 17 08:50:15.609979 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7852:tid 512] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I also tried changing the line:

```
zend_extension = \xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.6-vc11.dll
```

to

```
zend_extension = php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.6-vc11.dll
```

The

```
 Failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.6-vc11.dll
```

line in the error.log disappears.

But it still doesn't work.

I'm desperate, any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Log u provide and image screenshot show different kind of error. Image state that at moment u start Apache which configured to bind to port 80 and 443, those ports are already in use. U cant test what application occupy those ports "netstat -anob". U should at lease illuminate one error.

Comment: Anyway since u beginner, disable https in Apache, it isn't necessary in development.

Comment: I thought so too. The admin_panel errors are strange anyway, because Apache runs fine on the ports 8081 and 444. I have no clue, what some of the errorlogs are supposed to mean. Could it be possible that running XAMPP with https causes this problem?

Comment: Looks like u start the second instance of XAMMP. First instance was registered as service during installation.

Comment: About certificate error. My guess that u run default configuration of XAMMP, U have default configuration, virtualhost domain name www.example.com, but default certificate doesn't contain this host name.